# CVS equivilent to $id:$ in Accurev

Tags: perl, version-control, accurev

I am looking for a CVS equivalent to $id:$ in Accurev.

Before you start talking compile-time scripts - my major caveat is that a lot of my stuff is in Perl - so I can't do any of the normal "compile-time tricks" - as there really isn't much of any "compile-time" stuff.

I don't really want to require external files to define this stuff, as if (god forbid) the external definition files got out-of-sync with the actual scripts, etc...

I know I could always do some sort of compile-time preprocessor on the script files (to rewrite them) - but if there is a *cleaner* or better-integrated way of doing so (like "$id:$"   I'd appreciate anyone ideas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we get into more specifics, have you taken a look at the pre-keep trigger example AccuRev provides, addheader.pl?

You can find the example in the /AccuRev/examples/addheader.pl location.

Cheers,
~James